# Get text from tree structure SQL

Tags: sql, tree

i have category table with tree structure

every row has text for description Like below:

| nodeid | parentid | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | root description |
| 2 | 1 | sub category description |
| 3 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 4 | last description |

I want to show all the description from the root to the last category, like below:

**Description:**

root description.

sub category description.

last description

**how can I do this?**

thanks a lot

Comment: you need only in list of `description` right ?

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya yes i need only description for show.

Comment: waht is `tree` explain in your equation properly.

Comment: If i understand your equation is it's simple select query like this `select   description from tablename where description <> '' `

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya A tree is a tree structure of categories and subsets.
This is an example I wrote, I have over 2000 categories and subcategories in the table

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya I know how to write a SELECT query, i want when condition is nid=5 result like this : root description.
sub category description.
last description

Comment: You want a recusive query. Tag your DBMS, the feature is product specific.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya my DBMS is 2016

Comment: So, its SQL Server :-)

Comment: @rajorshi i know

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL (**MS SQLServer**) [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7a2bdd6aac46377b7bc7b208b29e6e4e):

```
WITH q
AS
(
  select nodeid,parentid,description from category where parentid=0
  union all
  select c.nodeid,c.parentid,c.description from category c inner join  q on q.nodeid=c.parentid
)
select description from q where description is not null;
```

**PostgreSQL** : [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=137c1c4adc08e6d55ad90c90c67c093d)

**Oracle** : [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dce4903f27d50336d0b6a24945d6a6bc)